# compilation.getLogger is not a function

Tags: webpack, copy, webpack-dev-server, copy-webpack-plugin

I upgraded `copy-webpack-plugin` from `4.6.0` to `6.0.2`

and I changed my code from

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: clientAssetPath,
      to: paths.STATICS,
      ignore: [ '.gitkeep' ],
    }], {
      debug: 'info'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      ...htmlPluginOptions,
    }),
    new DynamicCDNWebpackPlugin({
      resolver: unpkgResolver,
    }),
  ]
```

to

```
plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([{
      patterns: [{
        from: clientAssetPath,
        to: paths.STATICS,
        noErrorOnMissing: true
      }]
    }]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      ...htmlPluginOptions,
    }),
    new DynamicCDNWebpackPlugin({
      resolver: unpkgResolver,
    }),
  ]
```

as given on [official website](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/)

But it started throwing following error:
`compilation.getLogger is not a function`

When I debugged it I found error is coming from `node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js`
[image]
don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It needs upgrade of `webpack` as well https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/blob/master/package.json#L41

I could be able to fix the problem in following two ways

1. downgrading `copy-webpack-plugin` to 5.1.1 and using the old constructor fixes the issue for me.
2. Upgrading web-pack and resolve other syntax changes, caused by it